# ¿Cuándo cambiar el tipo de dato?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy creando una base de datos con tablas y tengo una duda en cuanto a la eficiencia de la misma.

Los tipos de datos de las tablas son TEXT, FLOAT y DATE-TIME. Los traigo de archivos CSV, por lo que la pregunta es: ¿Qué es más eficiente, transformarlos a su tipo de dato antes de escribir en la BS o después cuando los "lea"? ¿Los puedo introducir en la BBDD como TEXT o VARCHAR y cuando los quiera leer los transformo a su tipo correspondiente, o los transformo a su tipo real desde el char del CSV antes de escribir?

La lectura será un bucle por línea en PHP, después tengo que filtrar los repetidos, de manera que el bucle, si tiene que transformar cada dato a su tipo, quizás sea menos eficiente que leer línea a línea cada valor en su tipo original del CSV, que es string.

Comment: Es mejor que desde el inicio introduzcas cada dato según su tipo, no que tengas que manipular los datos luego de haberlos introducido, más aún si son muchos datos, pues pasarás horas/días/meses modificando datos. Para los repetidos lo mismo, en vez de introducir los datos sin verificar cuáles son repetidos para luego eliminarlos en la BD, me parece una mala idea. Mejor plantéate, en el programa que introducirá los datos, una lógica que verifique cuáles son repetidos y no los inserte, según los criterios que tengas establecidos. Tardarás menos creando esa lógica, que quitando repetidos.

Comment: Así lo haré. Pensaba mas en efectividad de la aplicación, pero la realidad es que no son muchos y probablemente el trabajo de normalización de la bbdd será mucho mayor. Mejor preparar los scripts que dejar tener que trabajar con los datos después.

Comment: Yo diría que las aplicaciones y los lenguajes de programación existen para facilitarnos la vida a nosotros. En este caso debes servirte de la aplicación para que haga ese trabajo en vez de hacerlo tú, no al revés. Saludos.